# Confidence interval for regression error, R,

Tags: r, prediction

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong here. I want to
    find a confidence interval for an average response of my variable
    "list1." R has an example online using the 'faithful' dataset and it
    works fine. However, whenever I try to find a confidence/prediction
    interval, I ALWAYS get this error message. I have been at this for 5
    hours and tried a million different things, nothing works.

```
 > list1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5)  #first data set
            > list2 <- c(2,4,5,6,7)   # second data set
            > frame <- data.frame(list1,list2) # made a data.frame object
            > reg <- lm(list1~list2,data=frame) # regression
            > newD = data.frame(list1 = 2.3) #new data input for confidence/prediction interval estimation
            > predict(reg,newdata=newD,interval="confidence") 
                fit         lwr      upr
        1 0.7297297 -0.08625234 1.545712
        2 2.3513514  1.88024388 2.822459
        3 3.1621622  2.73210185 3.592222
        4 3.9729730  3.45214407 4.493802
        5 4.7837838  4.09033237 5.477235
        Warning message:
        'newdata' had 1 row but variables found have 5 rows #Why does this keep happening??
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to pass in a new independent variable for prediction, but the `name` of that predictor matches the dependent variable from the initial model. The formula syntax in the regression is `y ~ x`. When you use the `predict()` function, you can pass new independent (x) variables. See the Details section of `?predict` for more details.

This however seems to work:

```
newD2 = data.frame(list2 = 2.3) #note the name is list2 and not list1
predict(reg, newdata = newD2, interval = "confidence")
---
       fit       lwr    upr
1 0.972973 0.2194464 1.7265
```